# $\sin(f(x))$ in binary series

Tags: sequences-and-series

We all know that sin function is defined like this: $$\sin { x } :\quad \left< -\infty ,+\infty  \right> \rightarrow \left[ -1,1 \right] $$ And it has Taylor series $$\sin { (x) } =\sum _{ k=0 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { { (-1) }^{ k }{ x }^{ 1+2k } }{ (1+2k)! }  } $$ but I was wondering if it has "binary series"? Since it can only produce values between -1 and 1 is there a way to produce it into a series that look more like this $$\sin { (x) } =-1+{ f }_{ 1 }(x)+{ f }_{ 2 }(x){ *2 }^{ -1 }+{ f }_{ 3 }(x){ *2 }^{ -2 }+{ f }_{ 4 }(x){ *2 }^{ -3 }+...$$ where $${ f }_{ i }(x)\in \left\{ 0,1 \right\} $$.

Now notice that
$$1=-1+1+1*{ 2 }^{ -1 }+1*{ 2 }^{ -2 }+1*{ 2 }^{ -3 }+...$$
$$0=-1+0+1*{ 2 }^{ -1 }+1*{ 2 }^{ -2 }+1*{ 2 }^{ -3 }+...$$
$$-1=-1+0+0*{ 2 }^{ -1 }+0*{ 2 }^{ -2 }+0*{ 2 }^{ -3 }+...$$

Now it should become obvious how the series is defined. My equation editor is not working properly so I'll just skip it.
In the same manner we could define $$\cos { (x) } =-1+{ g }_{ 1 }(x)+{ g }_{ 2 }(x){ *2 }^{ -1 }+{ g }_{ 3 }(x){ *2 }^{ -2 }+{ g }_{ 4 }(x){ *2 }^{ -3 }+...$$
and notice that since $$\sin ^{ 2 }{ (x) } ,\cos ^{ 2 }{ (x) } \ge 0$$ 
$$\sin ^{ 2 }{ (x) } :=-1+{ m }_{ 1 }(x)+{ m }_{ 2 }(x)*{ 2 }^{ -1 }+{ m }_{ 3 }(x)*{ 2 }^{ -2 }+...$$
$$\cos ^{ 2 }{ (x) } :=-1+{ n }_{ 1 }(x)+{ n }_{ 2 }(x)*{ 2 }^{ -1 }+{ n }_{ 3 }(x)*{ 2 }^{ -2 }+...$$
the values m and n for them respectively must be $${ m }_{ 1 }=1,{ n }_{ 1 }=1\\ { m }_{ i }+{ n }_{ i }=1\quad ,\quad i>1$$

My question is this: Using these definitions is there a formula for finding $${ f }_{ i }(x)$$ which involves only elementary functions?

Also a sub-question: What are the first few elements of this "binary series" for $$\cos { (x) } -\cos { (2x) } ?$$

Comment: I think you mean $f_i(x) \in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: yes of course, i'll edit it right now

Comment: Here is one difficulty you will face in defining such a series: while it is true that $0 = -1 + 0 + 2^{-1} + 2^{-2} + \cdots$, it is also true that $0 = -1 + 1$.  So should $f_1(\pi/2) = 1$ or $0$?

Comment: no, no problem there, i really should have written the definition so you could see that these values can not be "duplicated", I'll try to write it here $$ { f }_{ 1 }(x)=1,\quad x\quad \epsilon \quad \left< 0+2n\pi ,\quad \pi +2n\pi  \right ]$$

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can define those functions:
$$
f_k(x) = \left\{ \frac{1 + \sin x}{2^k} \right\}
$$
(here $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ is the sawtooth function). But those functions aren't at all nice. For starters, they aren't continuous.

Comment: I really wanted an answer that would not implement this solution.

Comment: Those are the functions, written in the simplest way possible. What did you have in mind? They are periodic (just as $\sin$ is), so they can be represented by a Fourier series.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but the problem with this is mainly that it breeds recursion.